# Custom route name with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, next.js

I started work on NextJS a few days ago, and I'm literally blocked now on something that, I think, is very stupid but I cannot find the solution on Internet...

For the moment my website has 4 pages (**Dashboard, Connexion, Register and Notes**) which are in '*pages*' folder at the same level than 'components' folder which has **Content, Footer, Header, Layout and Navigation.js**. Well, I have also a 'public' folder which contain a 'build' folder which has admin.js, app.css, app.js, two files .json and two others .js.

**Now, if I want to go on register page I have to type in the URL */register* but I would have to type */inscription* to go in.**

Hoping you understand everything and if you have any question, ask me ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your folder inside pages folder you should create,
dashboard.js, connection.js, register.js, notes.js.

Then if you run `npm run dev` you should be able to get in the url: `http://localhost:3000/register`

If you want to show your register page as SomeOtherPage you can use code below.

```
// pageWithLink.js
import Link from "next/link";
export default () => (
  <div>
    <Link href="/register" as="/SomeOtherPage">
      <a>Some Other Page</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: There is no other to modify the URL ?? For exemple if I type **"http://localhost:3000/test"** just get my **register.js** page ?

Comment: You can use `as` attribute in Link component of Next.js like following. `import Link from "next/link";
export default () => (
  <div>
    <Link href="/register" as="/anOtherPage">
      <a>An Other Page</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);`

Comment: Thank you very much **Hasan Sefa Ozalp**

Comment: This answer is wrong. the as attribute of next/link is used for dynamic routes only (https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes).

It does nothing but force change the url to that of its content, which does not solve OP problem.  In the example you provided, when user click on the Link it will just redirect them to /SomeOtherPage, not register page.